# UpdateOrCreate not updating data - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new to laravel.
I have an issue when I am trying to update or create record in DB.
I have a table called DspAccountFee with this columns:
[image]

I want to create record of dsp_account_id + screen_type when the combination not exists, and to update if the combination exists.
this is my code: (just tried to update the first row keys of -> dsp_account_id(5187) + screen type (ctv).  However nothing changed.

```
DspAccountFee::updateOrCreate(
                ['dsp_account_id' => $dsp_account_id, 'screen_type' => 'ctv'],
                ['pmp_percent' =>$fields['fee_ctv_pmp_percent'], 'omp_percent' => $fields['fee_ctv_omp_percent']]
                );
```

When I print the values before the DB operation they exists:

```
\Log::info("dsp_account:");
\Log::info($dsp_account_id);
\Log::info("ctv pmp percent:");
\Log::info($fields['fee_ctv_pmp_percent']);
\Log::info("ctv omp percent:");
\Log::info($fields['fee_ctv_omp_percent']);
\Log::info("app pmp percent:");
```

[image]

What I am missing why it is not update the db? Nothing in logs and No exception

this is my method in the model

```
protected $fillable = array(
        'dsp_account_id', 'screen_type'
    );
```

Comment: i would check $fillable property of the model, if those columns are missing from $fillable they will not be updated

Comment: do I need the DspAccountFee::updateOrCreate(  return a value? - I added the fillable in the model

Comment: Then you need to add your pmp_percent / omp_percent fields to it

Comment: sorry not understand what is your suggestion

Comment: to do this : `protected $fillable = array(
        'dsp_account_id', 'screen_type', 'pmp_percent', 'omp_percent'
    );` if you want to be able to update those fields

Comment: TNX it solved it,  If I want to update the updated_at column should I also add it to the fillable?

Comment: laravel handle that column for you, no need to update it manually, but if you really want to i guess you will have to add it to fillable too, not too sure they might be fillable by default

Answer (score 2):

Check the corresponding model and make sure that those columns exist in the
$fillable property. It should look somewhat like this.

```
  protected $fillable = [
  'dsp_account_id',
  'screen_type',
  'pmp_percent',
  'omp_percent'
];
```

Your updateOrCreate syntax looks okay.

To update the updated_at column in your database, you can use  the touch() method: you'll need to edit your code to something like this

```
 $foo = DspAccountFee::updateOrCreate([
    'dsp_account_id' => $dsp_account_id,
    'screen_type' => 'ctv'
    ],
    [
    'pmp_percent' => $fields['fee_ctv_pmp_percent'],
    'omp_percent' => $fields['fee_ctv_omp_percent']
    ]);

   $foo->touch();
```

Comment: TNX it is sloved, If I want also to update the updated at for example   'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()), do I need also to add it to the fillable?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include that bit of updating the updated_at column. I have made use of the touch() method.